# Xcode debugger doesn't display values for some variables, depending on scope

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

I am debugging a simple new mac os X app in Xcode.  I have a block of code in viewDidLoad().  Variables (Doubles) declared at the beginning of viewDidLoad() are displaying properly in the debug area, but some Doubles defined within a for loop are displaying blank values.  print() statements show the variables have values.  My code stops at a breakpoint within th for loop scope, so the variables should display.

Any reason for this behavior?

Over-simplified viewController.swift code example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var buyPrice: Double = 0.0
    var sellPrice: Double = 0.0
    ...

    for index in 0 ... roc5.percent.count-1 {
       ...
       let closeYearStart = stockPriceArray[currentYearStartIndex].close
       let closeYearEnd = stockPriceArray[currentYearEndIndex].close
       print("start: \(closeYearStart)")
       print("end:  \(closeYearEnd)")
       ...
     }
 }
```

When I recode this by moving the "closeYearStart" declaration OUTSIDE of the for loop (near "buyPrice" declaration), then that Double shows in the debugger, but "closeYearEnd", the Double declared within the for loop, still shows no value in the debugger.  The print statements confirm the values I expect.  The image below shows the state of the recoded version in the debugger when the breakpoint is reached.

So, as long as the Double variable is declared outside the for loop, the debugger shows the value as expected. Any Double declared inside the for loop has no value displayed.

This behavior confirms to me that Xcode doesn't show the variable within the for loop -- only those outside of the for loop.  Strings defined within the for loop display correctly, just problem with Double it seems.

Misc:

- I am using Xcode 11.5 (11E608c) under Catalina 10.15.5
- This is a debug build.  I have not set any optimization, etc.
- I have restarted Xcode, as well as "Clean Build Folder" and deleting "Derived Data" folder.

Is this  a known bug in Xcode?  In a prior project, URLs were always blank, so I had to recode to Strings to debug.  I can work around this, but it is really annoying.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image: d]